# Which sentence is wrong?

Tags: can-could

Take a look at this part of a conversation:

```
A: I got very wet walking home in the rain last night.

                     |1. You could have taken a taxi.
B: Why did you walk? |2. You could take a taxi.
                     |3. You was were able to take a taxi.
```

Which one of the numbered sentences is wrong? (WHY?)
Using 'could' confuses me! What's the difference between them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may interest you; however, in any case, you should indicate which answer *you* think to be correct, and why, and where your confusion lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right answer would be the first one.`Could + have` is used when you want to show that something is possible now or was possible at some time in the past.So, `You could have taken a taxi` is more appropriate here.
`Could` is used as past tense of `Can` and it is used `(1)` to talk about ability,`(2)` to say that something is possible or impossible,`(3)` to make a polite request and `(4)` To make a polite offer.

> (1) I can speak four languages. / I could run very fast when I was
>   younger.
>
> (2) Learning English can be difficult. / You couldn’t use computers in
>   the nineteenth century.
>
> (3) Can I go home now? / Could I go now please?
>
> (4) You can go whenever you like. / Could I give you a lift?

Comment: The question was not which is right; it was which is wrong.

Comment: Your discursion about uses of can does not seem to me to help a bit, given that two of the sentences use _could_, and the third uses _be able_, which in some senses is a synonym of _can_, but is not really in these uses.

Answer (score 1):

*You was* is not grammatical in any standard version of English, as far as I know, though it is used in some dialects.

If you correct *you was* to *you were*, all three are grammatical, and possible in context; but no 1. is very much the most idiomatic, in the context of "past unreal": that is, things that did not happen, but could have happened.